# Get iPhone physical color using the API

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'd like to access the information about the iPhone physical color using the official API but it seems Apple has not worked on this yet. Do you guys have a clue how to do this?
I want to design my apps so that the color scheme matches that of the iPhone physical design. This makes much sense now that the 5C revision goes a whole bench of crazy colors.